# "bower-installer" in front-end-maven gives error

Tags: maven, bower

I am using front-end-maven plugin to run npm and bower in maven. (https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md#working-directory) 
But I want to use bower-installer , which keeps only required min file instead of all the repo. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer).

But trying to include bower-installer gives me error in maven.

```
<execution>
<id>bower-installer</id>
<goals>
<goal>bower</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<arguments>-installer</arguments>
</configuration>
</execution>
```

This takes as bower -installer while doing maven build.

```
--- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:bower (bower-installer) @ tomcat7 ---
[INFO] Running 'bower -installer' in C:\Users\userName\workspace\samplePrj
[INFO] 
[INFO] Usage:
[INFO] 
[INFO]     bower <command> [<args>] [<options>]
```

But corresponding folder will not be created. Please note the space between bower and -installer. The command should be bower-installer.

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: Please see the edited question